# Is it reasonable to have a python file with the same name as a notebook file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Suppose I am working on some python code say in foo.py.

Is it reasonable to have a notebook named foo.ipynb and import foo in that notebook?

This seems to work, but is it a good idea?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see why not. As an aside, always use the generic [python] tag for all python-related questions.At this point, Python 3 *is* Python. Python 2 is passed its end of life. And, pragmatically, using the [python] tag gets more eyeballs on your question.

Comment: No problem with that,its fine

Answer (score 0):

Yes, technically you could that do with no issue, as long as yourself is comfortable with having those two files using the same name and different extension.

However, I would like to mention that at some point of time, people might want or need to change a notebook file to a single python script file. When that happens, it might be confusing. Thus, personally, if I have a foo.py, I would name my notebook as foo_notebook.ipynb, even if it seems reductant.